# Issue with Ruby variables

Tags: ruby

I expect this code to insert the four variables (which all contain only numerical characters) into the table in the SQLite database:

```
on :"1" do |m|
  local      = m.params[1]
  local_max  = m.params[2]
end

on :"2" do |m|
  global     = m.params[1]
  global_max = p m.params[2]
  db.execute( "insert into t (local, local_max, global, global_max) values(#{local}, #{local_max}, #{global}, #{global_max})" )
end
```

but instead, it generates some errors:

```
> [2016/01/07 20:43:09.662] !! bot.rb:88:in `block (4 levels) in
> <main>': undefined local variable or method `local' for
> #<Cinch::Callback:0x00000000c4fe00 @bot=#<Bot nick="cinch">> (NameError)
```

Comment: are you sure you wanted `db.execute` line inside the block, not outside?

Comment: Yes I do, because I know within the block all 4 variables have been set.

Comment: i do not know, what `on..` thing do, but it will only work, if these `on` blocks share the same scope. Otherwise you have the adequate error - you can not access local variables outside the scope of their definition

Comment: I thought that rule is only for `def` etc., no? `on` is part of Cinch gem.

Comment: As I said, I have no clue, what these blocks do, but it is Ruby's scoping, it works everywhere in the same way

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @sawa why undefined variable

Comment: An off-topic observation -- your code for calling `db.execute` is vulnerable to any kind of injection attack, unless you are absolutely sure that you are sanitizing the values somewhere else. Just something to be aware of if this code accepts untrusted input.

Comment: You should accept an answer if it helped you as courtesy to users who took time to answer your question.  Also, you get +2 reputation points for every accepts.

Answer (score 2):

The variables `local` and `local_max` exist only in the scope of the first block (the first `do`...`end`).

"Declaring" the variables outside the block and then letting the block capture them should be enough:

```
local, local_max = nil, nil
on :"1" do |m|
  local      = m.params[1]
  local_max  = m.params[2]
end

on :"2" do |m|
  global     = m.params[1]
  global_max = p m.params[2]
  db.execute( "insert into t (local, local_max, global, global_max) values(#{local}, #{local_max}, #{global}, #{global_max})" )
end
```

I (and everyone else, it seems) have no idea what `on` is, but it's worth noting that if `on` does any fancy metaprogramming that changes the scoping of the supplied block, this might not work.

Comment: Scoping takes place at a syntactic level. What's an example of fancy metaprogramming that could possibly change the lexical scope of the variables?

Comment: @drhining: that was me getting confused. It's pretty easy to change scope for methods and instance variables. It is possible though, using bindings (I think).

Answer (score 0):

Local variables are called local for reason - they are only visible within the scope of definition.

You are trying to access local variable defined in one block from another, which throws the adequate exception.

Comment: @user5603796, you can define local and local_max in the higher scope (before the two blocks) and everything will work.